# List Vs Datatable in web api response

Tags: c#

I'm new in web api and I wrote a code in which I return a datatable in an IHttpActionResult and I want to know what is the difference between return a datatable and a list or dictionary.

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication2.BLL;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {


        public IHttpActionResult getpro()
        {
            var tabla= new Conexion().table();
            tabla.TableName = "tablilla";

            return Ok(tabla);

        }


    }
}
```

I am testing this in post man and is runing well, but I want to know if should I sent a list in the response or another object.

Comment: *what is the difference between return a datatable and a list or dictionary* - simply return a datatable, list and a dictionary and watch the results in postman. That is the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might not be an apparent difference right now, but as your application grows, you *might* run into maintainability issues.

The issue is that right now, the signature of your API endpoint (i.e. what data it returns) is hard coupled to your database, so if you change your database, so does the result returned by your endpoint. That's usually a bad thing for anything but the smallest/simplest applications, since it might break consumers of your API.

What you'd do instead, is create models specifically for returning from your API endpoints and then convert (also called map) your datatable to a list of these "view"-models. This way, you can change the backend of your web API without it (immediately) having an impact on your frontend (or other consumers of your API).